# Javascript \ jQuery redirect with JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, redirect

i want to redirect a page and attach json data with it.

i am currently using window.location.href command
and i am adding GET paramaters with it.

how can i add JSON data?

THanks in advance

Comment: Add JSON data to what? Can you show what you have and what you want to do with it?

Comment: im am redirecting a page and would like to attach data. u can do that with POST or GET, but can u send via JSON?

Comment: So what would the redirection look like? What would the URL be>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible--using base64 encoding and a fragment identifier, you don't even have to send your data using GET.

- base64-encode your JSON object.  This will yield an url-save string, say `KJDF4822kdj`
- redirect to `http://your.domain/page#KJDF4822kdj` using `KJDF4822kdj` as a fragment identifier.
- on `page`, extract the fragment identifier using `window.location.hash`
- base64-decode the fragment and evaluate as JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it very easy to achieve this using Javascript/Jquery.

1) encode your JSON object using `base64-encode`. This will yield a string.
2) Append it to the end of the to-be-redirected-to-URL like URL#base64encodedJSONobjectVal
3) document.location.href = to-be-redirected-to-URL#base64encodedJSONobjVal

At the other page/target side,
1) retrieve the hash value using location.hash
2) strip the literal hash value.
3) decode the hashed value using `base64 decode`

Demo and more details https://gist.github.com/kmario23/66adb1922a245aa97576

Answer (score -1):

You can't. GET only works with a very simple JSON object (basically you can't use nested structures).

If you need something more complex, use a POST request `$.ajax(type='POST')` and you must serialize the object:

```
var jsonObjects = [{id:1, name:"amit"}, {id:2, name:"ankit"},{id:3, name:"atin"},{id:1, name:"puneet"}];

jQuery.ajax({
          url: <Url of the action>,
          type: "POST",
          data: {students: JSON.stringify(jsonObjects) },
          dataType: "json",
          beforeSend: function(x) {
            if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
              x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
            }
          },
          success: function(result) {
         //Write your code here
          }
});
```

Comment: There's no technical reason why you couldn't have a nested structure in a GET request. It would be poor design, but technically quite possible.

Comment: this will send to the page but will it redirect it to the url?